# Pass UInt32 as a parameter TestCase NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am using NUnit 3.8.1 and I am trying to do a really simple test:

```
    [TestCase(0)]
    [TestCase(11)]
    [TestCase(12)]
    [TestCase(13)]
    [TestCase(14)]
    public void GivenUserCreatesPinWhenItIsInWrongPositionThenThrowArgumentException(uint position)
    {
        //Assert
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() =>
        {
            new PositionPin(position);
        });
    }
```

And I get this exception:

> Message: System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.UInt32'

As soon as I change uint by int and cast the int to uint inside the method it works. I don't really want to do this, is there a way to keep my uint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use an `u` to directly tell the compiler, that the number is a `System.UInt32` number.

```
[TestCase(0u)]
[TestCase(11u)]
//...
```

Or: Use int as parameter and cast with (uint)

Comment: The OP is aware how to fix it. They ask how they can make it work with their unit testing framework that obviously doesn't know how to handle testfixtures that have an uint as parameter, so without the casting or changing the public interface of the method.

Comment: I agree.

TestCase(0u) will solve the problem without changing any interface.

Comment: NUnit `TestCase` does a lot of conversions. I didn't put that one in because it's so easy to just use the `u` suffix.